# Why is the DateTimeOffset.AddMonths(1).Date not the same as ((dto) => dto.AddMonths(1).Date)

Tags: c#, date, datetimeoffset

I have a helper function in domain logic:

```
private static DateTimeOffset CalculateNextDate(DateTimeOffset previousDate, TimeUnit timeUnit, int quantity)
{
    Func<int, DateTimeOffset, DateTimeOffset> calcMethod;
    switch (timeUnit)
    {
        case TimeUnit.Month:
            calcMethod = (i, offset) => offset.AddMonths(i);
            break;
        // ... [irrelevant] ...
        default:
        // ... [irrelevant] ...
    }
    return calcMethod(quantity, previousDate).Date;
}
```

When my unittest tried to validate a month for example:

```
    // Arrange
    int monthsToAdd = 1;
    var timeUnit = TimeUnit.Month;
    var sut = new TimeInterval(timeUnit, monthsToAdd);
    var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    // Act
   var result = sut.NextDate(now);

    // Assert
     var expectedDate = now.AddMonths(1).Date;
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedDate, result);  // FAILS
```

The assert fails because the expectedDate is `{26/04/2017 0:00:00}` while the result is `{26/04/2017 0:00:00 +02:00}`

I don't understand why one can keep the offset while the other ditches it.  Is it because I cast the `.Date` to a DateTimeOffset? Can't find the explanation on msdn...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`DateTimeOffset.Date` page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This property removes any significant part of the time component from a DateTimeOffset object and returns only its significant date component. **For example, if the DateTimeOffset object has a date and time value of "1/12/07 4:01pm +7:30", the property returns a DateTime value of "1/12/07 12:00:00 AM"**. The DateTime value can then be displayed by using any of the standard or custom format specifiers that display dates only. (See the Example section for an illustration.)
>
> **The value of the DateTime.Kind property of the returned DateTime object is always DateTimeKind.Unspecified. It is not affected by the value of the Offset property.**

See also the [DateTimeOffset Constructor (DateTime) page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337819(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This constructor's behavior depends on the value of the DateTime.Kind property of the dateTime parameter:
>
> - If the value of DateTime.Kind is DateTimeKind.Utc, the DateTime property of the new instance is set equal to dateTime, and the Offset property is set equal to Zero.
> - **If the value of DateTime.Kind is DateTimeKind.Local or DateTimeKind.Unspecified, the DateTime property of the new instance is set equal to dateTime, and the Offset property is set equal to the offset of the local system's current time zone.**

Thus, by converting to `DateTime` using the `Date` property, you remove the time component, but you also remove the offset and `Kind`.

When you converted from `DateTimeOffset` to `DateTime` then implicitly cast back to `DateTimeOffset`, it assumes that this is a time at the current timezone.

Comment: That's it!  I overlooked the constructor explanation.